# javascript in acrobat to find top 5 maximum responses with text values from an associated field

Tags: javascript, acrobat

I am working on a quiz in Acrobat and I need to take 19 group input values and calculate the top 5 values, then output the corresponding text of those values in another field.  So it would be something like this:

Group 1: 25 Healer
Group 2: 24 Minister
Group 3: 13 Hospitality
...
Group 19: 21 Giving

New form would show

1. Healer: You are a person with healing abilities
2. Minister: You are a person with ministering abilities
   etc

Any thoughts?

Comment: Hi Deb, welcome to StackOverflow. Please could you provide a bit more information on what you've tried already, including any code, and possibly a screenshot and/or diagram to give a rough idea of what you're trying to achieve. Additional information would make your question a little bit clearer and easier to answer, and less abstract. Additionally, it might be easier to follow if you edit your question to format the "Group 1..." etc and new form parts to be one on each line, it's currently a bit difficult to decipher meaning from.

Comment: I posted a suggested edit, I think Deb is able to accept it @Harry

Comment: Well, I'm not exactly sure what to give you for what I have tried since my coding skills are fairly minimal - I did some a long time ago and can't really remember much, but maybe this will help . . .

Comment: So what I have for items are the following. N1   Minister/Planting         Some additional text
N2   Preaching      Some additional text
N3   Evangelist      Some additional text
N4   Pastor            Some additional text
N5   Teacher          Some additional text
N6   Encouragement  Some additional text
N7   Wisdom         Some additional text
N8   Knowledge   Some additional text
N9   Serving          Some additional text                           up to N19

Comment: So output would look something like this:

1 25 Wisdom Blah blah blah
2 24 Faith Blah blah blah
3 21 Healing Blah blah blah
4 19 Pastor Blah blah blah
5 17 Minister/Planting Blah blah blah